# Draw straight line that not connected in a graph using c#

Tags: c#

I have a set of float value that store inside a list. I would like to use these value to plot a graph . There are zero value that inside the list. Now, what I want to do is plot the line graph using these values and if there is any zero value found in the list, it will skip and continue. Which mean there will be a break among the line graph and I do not want to connect it to zero values. How do I plot the graph? Thanks. Hope you understand what I mean.

```
        chart1.Series.Add("series1");
        chart1.Series["series1"].BorderWidth = 4;
        chart1.Series["series1"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;


        for (int i = 0; i < value.Count; i++)
        {
            if (value[i] != 0)
            {
                chart1.Series["series1"].Points.Add(value[i]);
            }
        }
```

Here is my code but the line graph join the zero point to form one line I do not want the graph connect to zero values.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you post some code that you have tried

Comment: "a graph using C#" does not tell anyone how you are doing the drawing of the line or what you want it to look like exactly.  You should also post your code that is not working the way you want it to.  The purpose of this forum is to fix code, not write it for you.

Comment: Sorry for didnt post out the code because I think my code is the wrong way to do it. Now I edited my question already. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < value.Count; i++)
{
    if (value[i] != 0)
    {
            chart1.Series["series1"].Points.Add(value[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        var point = chart1.Series["series1"].Points.Add(value[i]);
        point.IsEmpty = true;
    }
}
```